# How to reserve 2dimention vector with pair

Tags: c++, vector, std

I want to access the two-dimensional vector index directly.

but i dont know how to reserve

```
vector<pair<<vector<int>, int>>..
```

what should i do ?

```
           vector<pair<vector<int>, int>> c_list;

           vector<int> population;

           population.push_back(1);
           population.push_back(2);
           population.push_back(3);

           c_list[0].first = population;
```

vector out of range

Comment: You can just use `reserve` and `resize` like anything else.

Comment: c_list.reserve(5); << An error occurred

Comment: [Works fine.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6134aff279473946). Voting to close for lacking a [MCVE].

Comment: I know how to reserve 1 demetion vector.

Comment: Note that `reserve` changes the capacity of the vector, but not the size. If you only reserve, indexing will still be out of bounds.

Comment: I was a little confused. Thank you

Comment: Please make an effort to write a good question to avoid it being closed, you are far more likely to get a useful answer if your question is very clear.  please review how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Newbies must be given an opportunity to improve their question https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `reserve` only changes the capacity of the vector but not the size. It can improve performance for large `vector`s because many `push_back`s could lead to internal `resize` operations in the `vector` with multiple allocations and deallocations which may take time.

In your example, simply call `c_list.resize(1);` before `c_list[0].first = population;` and you should be fine. `resize` really changes the size immediately.